# Kivy | Screen won't change until the end of the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, screen

I'm trying to create a tool using Python and using Kivy as the GUI. When the tool is run by the user I want a Progress Bar to display. I achieved this by using Kivy screens.  I have a main menu screen, file chooser popup window and a progress bar.

The screens work fine, however the progress bar(screen) will only change from the main menu once the rest of the method has completed. Even though I have told the screen to change. This defeats the point of the progress bar as the tool has already finished running when the screen finally changes.

I can't seem to get around this issue. I tried using pop up windows but I got the same issue. By inserting a few breakpoints and using the debugger I can see the Screen Manager has realised the change but does not change screens until the end of the program.

main.py

```
#When run button is pressed the run method is called
import sys
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import os
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen



class MainScreen(Screen):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    # Dissmiss Popup aka cancel button
    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    # File Browser
    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Select Disk Image", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    # Select file function
    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])):
            global diskimage
            diskimage = filename[0]

    # When the run button is clicked
    # Makes sure they have to select a file before pressing run
    def run(self):
        if diskimage is None:
            "Please Select a Disk Image"
        else:
            print("Initialising")
            # calling BulkExrtaor class
            print("screen currently set to:", self.manager.current)

            self.manager.current = 'progressbar'

            print("screen currently set to:", self.manager.current)

            BulkExtractor().bulkextractor_run()
            #p1.start()
            print(self.manager.current)
            print("changed?")
    def startBE(self):
        BulkExtractor().bulkextractor_run()


class AnotherScreen(Screen):

    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class GUI_RUN(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

class BulkExtractor(MainScreen):

    #Bulk Extractor run method
    def bulkextractor_run(self):
         print("File Path to file", "\"" + diskimage + "\"")

         #Runs Bulk Extractor
         #command im trying to run
         # os.system("%Programdata%\\bulk_extractor64.exe -o output ""\"" + diskimage + "\"")

        #Using sleep as a test instead of trying to run the actual command above
         print("Still hasn't changed")
         time.sleep(20)
         print("Still hasn't changed")

         print("Program Finished")

class Progressbar(ScreenManager):
    pass

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI_RUN().run()
```

Main.kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            font_size: 50
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            text: "FD"
            pos_hint: {"right": 0.65,'top':1}

        Button:
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            text: "Select Disk Image"
            pos_hint: {"right": 0.65,'top':0.5}
            on_press: root.show_load()

        Button:
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            text: "Run"
            pos_hint: {"right": 0.65,'top':0.3}
            on_press: root.run()

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            path: "C:/"

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Select"
                on_press: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
                on_release: root.cancel()

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: 'progressbar'
    Label:
        text: 'Progress: {}%'.format(int(pb.value))
        size_hint_y: None
        pos: 10, 400
        font_size: 30
    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        min: -100
        max: 100
        value: 0
        size_hint: 0.5 , 1.0
        width: 200
        pos : 200, 70

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
        text: 'Cancel'
        size_hint_x: .3
        size_hint_y: .1
        pos: 290, 190
        font_size:
```

After the processing class/method, the screen changes....

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

To test this run the code and select any file on your system and hit run.

Comment: With the code that you have provided, it is hard to help you. Please provide more code.

Comment: This code will produce a syntax error at `'progressbar`

Comment: ikoim I have edited the post to show the full code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a common problem in that your `bulkextractor_run()` method is running on the main thread, thus keeping the main thread busy, so that it can't update any GUI elements. To get it to work correctly, run that method in a different thread:

```
def run(self):
    if diskimage is None:
        "Please Select a Disk Image"
    else:
        print("Initialising")
        # calling BulkExrtaor class
        print("screen currently set to:", self.manager.current)

        self.manager.current = 'progressbar'

        print("screen currently set to:", self.manager.current)

        Thread(target=BulkExtractor().bulkextractor_run).start()

        print(self.manager.current)
        print("changed?")
```

Then, in your `bulkextractor_run()` method, you need to do the `ProgressBar` updates back on the main thread, perhaps using `Clock.schedule_once()`, like this:

```
class BulkExtractor(MainScreen):


    #Bulk Extractor run method
    def bulkextractor_run(self):
         print("File Path to file", "\"" + diskimage + "\"")

         #Runs Bulk Extractor
         #command im trying to run
         # os.system("%Programdata%\\bulk_extractor64.exe -o output ""\"" + diskimage + "\"")

        #Using sleep as a test instead of trying to run the actual command above
         for i in range(101):
             time.sleep(0.1)
             Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update_progressBar, i))

         print("Program Finished")

    def update_progressBar(self, val, dt):
        presentation.get_screen('progressbar').ids.pb.value = val
```

Comment: Thank you, @John Anderson, this solved my issue! Been stuck on this for the last few days ....

Comment: The answer posted by @ikolim mentions several issues that you should attend to.